# How to use RoboSpice to listen server pushed data on a socket?

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, real-time, robospice

I am trying to use RoboSpice to maintain a persistent TCP socket for my app. (Many people do not suggest keep a persistent connection for battery life concern, however, my app is a real-time one so I need to keep a connection open). Not only I need to send requests to the remote server, but also I wish to listen for the incoming data from the socket. The RoboSpice wiki & sample showcased how to send a request, but how to leverage the framework to handle incoming data and do something upon the delivery of incoming data?

@Snicolas, Thank you for the good work. Could you please give me some hints? Thank you.